# Wordpress Visual Composer, Woocommerce Featured Product with short description

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the Visual Composer plugin on Wordpress. On the Featured Products (Woocommerce) element, is it possible to add a short description underneath the Product Title? would this best be done in functions.php?

The website is using a theme where a child theme has not been created and I'm not sure how much of the theme has been changed/edited. I don't want to edit the theme files!!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can. Just paste this lines of code into your theme's woocommerce/content-product.php file right after this line

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

global $product;
if ( $product->is_featured() ) {
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt 
  );
}
```

Comment: Short Description will come from product backend short description textarea field.